# I think I have peace lily and the looks not so great

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care

[image]

I have kept them around two months and the first time I got it was looking really good and then I can put them into new pot. That’s all I didn’t change the soil and I water it for a few days it just look like on this picture and since that day until today, it’s still looking like this, and I still don’t know how to fix it . I thought at first it just gonna be back naturally but it been 2 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't adding them fertilizers enough. Also, when you overwater plants, It tricks plant to get acclimated to being in water and the plant focuses on root growth to stand in that heavily saturated soil. In extreme cases of overwatering you get a rot. Making them struggle a bit for water a bit will make them go from that vegetative phase to blooming phase for its survival hy offsprings.

Water it less often and add a MAP or DAP based fertilizer.

Comment: How about fertilizer mono potassium phosphate?

Comment: Sounds better to me. But first I'll like you to conduct a pH test of soil using Universal indicator or any other soil test. Peace lilies prefer slightly acidic soils. If yours is a bit alkaline, MAP would work wonders. If it's already a bit acidic MAP will do more harm than good, then in that case opt for DAP, since it's a bit on alkaline side and will help lower your soil acidity.